# Firebase Database: Telling me I have data, when I don't

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I'm using a FutureBuilder, and for some reason, the snapshot is saying I have data when I don't. I don't even have a child named "Names".

Database.dart:

```
class Database {
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  Future<DataSnapshot> names () async {
    return dbRef.child("Names").once();
  }
}
```

Future Builder's stream:

```
Future<DataSnapshot> names () async {
   return dbRef.child("Names").once();
}
```

My Future Builder:

```
FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
     future: Database().names(),
     builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snap2) {
        if (snap2.hasData) {
           // It's returning this when it shouldn't
           return Text("Has Data");
        } else {
           // But not returning this
           return Text("No Data");
        }
    }
 ),
```

Database in JSON format:

```
{
 "Letters" : {
   "letter" : "Some text here"
 }
}
```

Am I missing something? I do have a child called "letters", and I believe it's counting that as having data, but I'm only wanting to check if Names exists or has data for that child.

Comment: add ur database, also what is dbref equal to

Comment: I've updated the question with it included

Comment: I'm not suppose to post again really, but I'm desperate at this point. does anybody have any ideas? I can't seem to solve this and I've looked absolutely everywhere  with no answers

Comment: Can you show your database? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sure. I've gone ahead and updated the question. Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it

Comment: Think you need to check what span2 actually contains. hasData returns true if the snapshot is non-null. So it is possible you are getting an empty map/list returned, which qualifies as non-null.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay. How would I check it?

Comment: Viewing snap2 in a debugger, printing it (or snap2.value and snap2.key) to string should work. I haven't used FutureBuilder for dB calls as I typically await the results in my app. In my case I check the snapshot.value contains something because snapshot will always contain the key of the query.